# What does アレだし mean?

Tags: meaning

Context: the speaker is a little worried about giving her real name during registration, and says,「本名そのままって いうのもアレだし。どうしょうかな。」

Because of the context, I understand the meaning in this example. But what does 「アレだし」mean in general? When can one use it?

A secondary question (not sure if it's related to the main question): why 「いうのも」rather than 「いうのは」?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26127/need-help-with-translating-%E4%BB%8A%E6%9B%B4%E8%81%9E%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AE%E3%82%82%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AC%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%A9

Comment: For this も, see also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65647/5010

Comment: Thanks, this clears things up!

Comment: And btw why is it いう rather than 使う or 書く？After all, during registration, the name isn't spoken, but written.