# Do some noun suffixes require specific kinds of nouns?

Tags: grammar, suffixes

The examples I've seen of [中]{ちゅう} as a suffix seem to only use nouns that can form suru-verbs, such as [準備]{じゅんび}中. I assume I can't use it for most ordinary nouns, because people say 〜の[中]{なか} instead.

Is there any kind of general rule for this, or a category for noun suffixes that expect a suru verb-forming noun? More generally, is there a way to figure out how productive a given suffix is?

What about if I use a pronoun along the lines of [this sort of アレ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/101121)? Can it be understood as standing for such a compatible noun?

Comment: There's also 考え中. I see this 考え more as a verb stem than a noun.

Answer (score 1):

The ～中｛ちゅう｝suffix means 'in the middle of doing something', basically. 家中｛いえちゅう｝ makes no sense because a house is not an action, and would be interpreted as 家中｛いえじゅう｝ 'all over the house'. ～の中 usually just means 'inside something'.

I don't believe there are too many suffixes of this nature so it should be easy enough to learn them all.

Comment: I understood the specific meanings here, but I'm looking more for a general *grammatical* principle.

Comment: What counts as a grammatical explanation?

Comment: Well, for example, I should be able to understand if there are rules for it, or if I just memorize a list of suffixes that work like 中 vs. others that take any noun. I also still have the question about substituting the noun with アレ etc.